# How to convert javascript data attributes as array

Tags: custom-data-attribute, slick.js

I am trying to develop a library object for slick carousel that passes the parameters in a data object. However I found that data objects can only be a string.  I have found similar posts, but only for string to json.
Eval or split(",") does not work, btw...

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="carousel container-fluid no-margin" data-params="{dots: true, arrows: true, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}">
```

JS:

```
             var loadCarousel = function(element) {
                    var carousel = $(element).find('.carousel');
                    var params;
                    if($(carousel).find('.single-item').length && !$(carousel).find('.single-item').hasClass('slick-initialized')) {  

                        params =  $(carousel).data('params'); // need to convert from a string to an array

                        $(carousel).find('.single-item')          
                            .slick(
                              params 
                            );

                    }

                }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert string into object but in your case you have to done some pre-processing to the string because for JSON.parse(), the string should be like '{"hello":"world"}'. Currently the string is in this form '{hello:world}'. I coded a small script in plain JS which convert string into the correct form for JSON.parse(). You can do it like this.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("c");
var dataParams = a.getAttribute('data-params');
var newStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i<dataParams.length; i++){
  if(dataParams[i]=="{"){
    newStr = newStr+'{"';
  }
  else if(dataParams[i]==":"){
    newStr = newStr+'":';
  }
  else if(dataParams[i]==" "){
    newStr = newStr+' "'; 
  }
  else if(dataParams[i]==","){
    newStr = newStr+'",'; 
  }
  else if(dataParams[i]=="}"){
    newStr = newStr+'"}'; 
  }
  else{
    newStr = newStr + dataParams[i];
  }
}

var p = JSON.parse(newStr);
console.log(p.dots);
```

```html
<div id ="c" class="carousel container-fluid no-margin" data-params="{dots: true, arrows: true, autoplay: true, autoplaySpeed: 4000}">
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah:

Thank you for your answer.

I cannot use JSON: the library uses an array for options.  See documentation here:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: variable 'p' is an object and you can pass object to slick initialization. I did it many times by passing an object to initialize slick.

Comment: Thank you, Abdullah